# Border on div doesn't align with border on table header in Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a table with a header, and I'm trying to place a div next to it such that it appears to be an extension of the table header. This works fine in Firefox: (the X is in a div separate from the thead)

[image: Table Header in Firefox]

But in Chrome the border is offset by one pixel:

[image: Table Header in Chrome]

When I inspect the elements in Chrome, both the thead and the div are the same height, so it's strange that their borders would end up in different places. If I add a 1px margin to the top of the div, the border lines up but it creates a one pixel tall gap at the top.

Here's a codesandbox that shows what I'm dealing with. This example is using [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/).
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-hooks-gf6cx View it in Firefox and Chrome to see the difference.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll need to post your code in your question. A [mcve]

Comment: There is code in the codesandbox.

Comment: You're not understanding my point. Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to a 3rd party site otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome calculate the height of table with 1px more, it seems a bug.

<s>To fix you can add the display block to tr
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-tu-muw2m</s>

**EDIT:**

You can create a div inside a th element to avoid bug:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-microservice-ltz40

Comment: That seems to work, but when there is content in the table it causes the header to not act as a table anymore, and the columns are no longer aligned with the table elements.

Comment: if you want to mantain table aspect, create a div inside each th element to calculate the corret height. it seems chrome not calculate correct height with box-sizing on table, table -cell, etc. I update the link

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. It has mostly fixed my problem, but there now seems to be a small one pixel gap between the header and the div that only appears on Chrome. I can't seem to replicate it in the code sandbox. I am pretty tired of dealing with tables, to be honest. Is it better to just use flexbox? https://i.imgur.com/y9hL2PE.png